# Is there a difference between a bivariate VAR and an AR?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

I have two questions related to VAR and AR.

First question:
**What exactly is the difference between a VAR and AR?**

Second question:
**Is the application of a two-variable VAR not the same as an AR with two variables?**

Comment: AR is univariate, so a bivariate VAR is not the same as AR.